# SSL Certificate will not save

Tags: iis-7, ssl-certificate

I am trying to install an SSL Certificate (from GoDaddy.com) onto IIS 7.  I can add the certificate following the directions found [here](http://www.globalsign.com/support/install/install_iis7.php) and it shows up in my list of Server Certificates but once I leave the Server Certificates page and return to it, the certificate no longer shows up in the list.

This certificate is also used on an Apache box to authenticate our website (I am using IIS for a WCF Service API).  The certificate is assigned to *.mydomain.com so I thought I could use it for the Apache website server (www.mydomain.com) as well as my API (services.mydomain.com).  Am I incorrect in this assumption?  Do I need to do something different then the instructions I referenced above to install?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you ever find out what the problem was?

Comment: Have you managed to solve it? I have the same problem.

Comment: What was your solution?

Comment: Don't leave us hanging if you found a solution....

Answer (score 3):

Brian,

I assume you just grabbed the .cer file and imported this onto your IIS box. Sadly this is not possible as your certificate will not contain a private key so it won't be an option in IIS.

The GlobalSign instruction you referenced are fine but that is if you created the CSR on the IIS server itself.

What you will have to do is to create a PFX from from your .key and .cer files from the Apache server and then you can import this PFX onto your IIS Server followed by assigning it for use.

So use this to create your PFX file;
https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1229676-back-up-certificate---apache-openssl

Followed by;
https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1217281

As for everyone else if you just have a .CER file you and did not create the request you need a private key. So create a new CSR and request a reissue from your relevant CA.

The fact you cannot assign a certificate in IIS is because you do not have a private key that corresponds to the certificate.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. If you have access to the old machine you first created the certificate just go to that and export ".pfx" file from the certificate, then in the new machine you could easily import it and Done.
2. If you don't have access to the old machine, so you must reissue the SSL certificate with the help of the seller company.

Hope this help.

Answer (score -2):

See how godaddy response for this case: 
https://sg.godaddy.com/community/SSL-And-Security/completing-certificate-request-disappears-from-server/td-p/36299

But it doesn't work.
I tried in my way :
- Use https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html to convert my CRT file to PFX file.
- Then go to the IIS -> Server certificates -> Import -> Choose the generated PFX file in previous step.
It worked with me.